# How to eliminate strings that are equal to or the reverse of an anagram result?

Tags: php, arrays, anagram

> I've gotten close to what I want here. I've run into some logic issues with NOT    displaying results if they are equal to or the reverse of said result. I am looking for the anagram of two American state names that are the anagram of two other state names. I have found the solutions, now it's really just a display issue........I think. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
function anagramOf ($array, $start, $len) 
{
    global $i;
    $word = implode ("", $array);
    $i = ++$i;
    printf ("%'.-20d%'.20s%s", $i, ucfirst($word), "<BR>  \n");
}

function sortstr ($astring)
{
    global $word, $s, $l;
    $s = strtolower ($astring);
    $array = preg_split ('//', $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    sort ($array);
    $s = implode ("", $array);
}

function search ($aword,$pairs)
{
    global $len, $word, $s, $i;

    $size = count ($pairs);
    for ($k = 0; $k < $size; $k++)
    {
    $pairs[$k] = chop ($pairs[$k]);
        if (strlen ($pairs[$k]) == $len)
        {
            $l = $pairs[$k];
            sortstr ($l);
            $ls = $s;

            if (!strcmp ($ls, $word))
            {
            $i = ++$i;                  
            printf ("%'.-20d%'.20s%s", $i, ucfirst ($l),    "</br</br>");   
            }                       
        }
    }
}


$states1 = array("Alabama","Alaska","Arizona","Arkansas","California","Colorado","Connecticut","Delaware","Florida","Georgia","Hawaii","Idaho","Illinois","Indiana","Iowa","Kansas","Kentucky","Louisiana","Maine","Maryland","Massachusetts","Michigan","Minnesota","Mississippi","Missouri","Montana","Nebraska","Nevada","New Hampshire","New Jersey","New Mexico","New York","North Carolina","North Dakota","Ohio","Oklahoma","Oregon","Pennsylvania","Rhode Island","South Carolina","South Dakota","Tennessee","Texas","Utah","Vermont","Virginia","Washington","West Virginia","Wisconsin","Wyoming");

$states2 = array();
$states2 = $states1;

$pairs = array();
$countS1 = count($states1);
$countS2 = count($states2);
$countPr;

$i=0;
foreach($states1 as $s1array)
{
    $j=0;
    foreach($states2 as $s2array)
    {       
        $pairs[]=array($s1array => $s2array);   
        $j++;   
    }
    $i++;
}

$pCountPair = count($pairs);    
$newpairs = array();
$l=0;
foreach($pairs as $p => $pairs2)
{
    foreach($pairs2 as $name1 => $name2)
    {   
        $newpairs[]=$name1.$name2;;
    }
    $l++;
}

$p2count = count($newpairs);
#echo 'p2 = '.$p2count.'</br>';

for($r = 0; $r < $p2count; $r++)
{   
    $word = $newpairs[$r];
    echo "Anagrams of <b>".ucfirst ($word)."</b> :\n<BR>\n";
    $na = $word;

    sortstr ($word);
    $word = $s;
    $len = strlen ($word);
    $i = 0;
    search ($word,$newpairs);

}   
if ($i == 0)

    echo "Can't find any anagram of <B>".ucfirst($na)."</B> in the pairs array.</br></br>";             
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the biggest problem is the way you are joining the states together. In your list of states you are matching you are matching AlabamaAlaska and AlaskaAlabama.  So a good thing to do is only match unique two state combinations.

```
$doubleStates = array();

for ($i = 0, $max = count($states); $i < $max; $i++) {
    // The first loop starts from the first element of the array
    for ($j = $i + 1; $j < $max; $j++) {
        // The second loop starts from the next element of the first loop
        $doubleStates[] = $states[$i] . $states[$j];
    }
}
```

I probably shouldn't write all your code for you but I got carried away:

```
<?php

function findAnagrams($array) {
    do {
        $matcher = null;
        $matches = array();
        foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
            if (is_null($matcher)) {
                unset($array[$key]);
                $matcher = $val;
            } elseif (isAnagram($matcher, $val)) {
                if (empty($matches)) {
                    $matches[] = $matcher;
                }
                $matches[] = $val;
            }
        }

        if (count($matches) > 0) {
            print_r($matches);
            echo "<br >";
        }
    } while (count($array) > 0);
}

function isAnagram($a, $b) {
    return letterize($a) == letterize($b);
}

function letterize($a) {
    $array = str_split(str_replace(' ', '', strtolower($a)));
    sort($array);
    return join($array);
}

$states = array('Alabama','Alaska','Arizona','Arkansas','California','Colorado',
    'Connecticut','Delaware','Florida','Georgia','Hawaii','Idaho','Illinois',
    'Indiana','Iowa','Kansas','Kentucky','Louisiana','Maine','Maryland',
    'Massachusetts','Michigan','Minnesota','Mississippi','Missouri','Montana',
    'Nebraska','Nevada','New Hampshire','New Jersey','New Mexico','New York',
    'North Carolina','North Dakota','Ohio','Oklahoma','Oregon','Pennsylvania',
    'Rhode Island','South Carolina','South Dakota','Tennessee','Texas','Utah',
    'Vermont','Virginia','Washington','West Virginia','Wisconsin','Wyoming');

$doubleStates = array();

for ($i = 0, $max = count($states); $i < $max; $i++) {
    for ($j = $i + 1; $j < $max; $j++) {
        $doubleStates[] = $states[$i] . $states[$j];
    }
}

findAnagrams($doubleStates);
```

Comment: This cleaned up nice, thanks. Though, what about other matches? It seems to stop too early. For example...South Dakota & North Carolina?

Comment: yeah South Dakota/North Carolina - North Dakota/South Carolina is the anagram

Comment: Right-Thanks again. I spent a fair amount of time trying to take the results of EVERY possibility (to include the original string and it's reverse), putting those into an array-then filtering out the duplicates. Needless to say, I didn't get that to work yet.